# Executing Powershell from Perl

Tags: perl, powershell

I have a bunch of Powershell scripts which I need to run from Perl. I have the following code but for some reason the Powershell scripts dont get invoked. I have tried both the backtick and the system command

```
$path = "C:/Users/PSScript.ps1";
$pwspath = "c:/windows/system32/windowspowershell/v1.0/powershell.exe";

$output = `$pwspath -command $path`;

system($pwspath -command $path);
```

Please help me out here.

Comment: Hint: try adding `use strict; use warnings;` to the top of your script and try again.

Comment: Are you sure you want backticks? Backticks are used to capture what is printed to console output as a result of running the command. `system` is more appropriate for invoking scripts.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use -File instead of -Command

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your code is formatted correctly? Shouldn't you be using quotes?

```
system("$pwspath -command $path");
```

Backtick should work, try:

```
my @stdout = `$pwspath -command $path`;
print join("\n", @stdout),"\n";
```

Comment: hi,

system() works but backtick doesnt

tried the following

`"$pwspath -command $path"`;

system("$pwspath -command $path")

any ideas for backtick, since I need to capture the stdout and then format it