# How to get the error or message after executing a cmdlet in perl

Tags: perl, cmd

I am using this command to search and get file details on a remote server

```
my $output=`psexec \\\\host cmd /c "dir /s d:\\folder\file`
```

if the files are present it will display all the files and its path and they are stored in `$output` if the path is not found or if the server does  not exist it returns the following on the cmd but not to `$output`

`Starting cmd on host...ice on host...
The system cannot find the path specified.
cmd exited on host with error code 1.`

How can i get the message from the cmd or report error ,i tried `$!` doesn't return anything

Comment: https://perldoc.perl.org//perlop.html#qx%2f_STRING_%2f

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are on modern day Windows machines, PowerShell can be used and no need for psexec. The remote machine needs to be setup for remoting. `Get-Help about_Remote_Requirements` and `Enable-PSRemoting`.

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName HOST001  -ScriptBlock { & cmd /c dir /s D:\thedir\ }
```

For running PowerShell from Perl, see [Executing Powershell from Perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770124/executing-powershell-from-perl)

Answer (score 2):

You have to check the stdin, stderr and probably the exit code of the executed command. There are several modules to help you in that task, like [Capture::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Capture::Tiny)

```
use Capture::Tiny ':all';

# Capture from external command
# Adapt $cmd and @args to your needs

my $cmd = 'psexec';
my @args = ( );

my ( $stdout, $stderr, $exit_code ) = capture {
  system( $cmd, @args );
};
```

Comment: I get the error `this hande is invaild and error accessing the node` if i put this entire command `psexec \\\\host cmd /c "dir /s d:\\folder\file` in the `system` function